# How to modify the existing multipass instance configuration?

Tags: multipass

I have created the multipass instance with 4GB Ram and 1 CPU. I want upgrade instance to 6GB + 2 CPUS.

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: https://multipass.run/docs/modify-an-instance#heading--set-the-cpu-ram-or-disk-of-an-instance

Answer (score 2):

Stop the vm:

```
$ multipass stop NAME
```

Set the resources:

```
$ multipass set local.NAME.cpus=2
$ multipass set local.NAME.memory=6G
```

Start the vm:

```
$ multipass start NAME
```

Comment: Official doc (which sadly doesn't include examples): https://multipass.run/docs/modify-an-instance
You can use "get" to see the current value (namely, the default RAM seems to be 1GiB which is quite limited depending on your use case)
Don't forget the "local" part which is needed for some reason

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

I tried but it is not working. I think multipass doesn't allow to edit resources after creation. 

I am using VMWARE now.